# Convert ArrayList to LinkedList

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

If I want to change this implementation from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` do I just have to change

```
ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

to

```
LinkedList<Character> characters = new List<Character>();
```

Or how do I do this?

```
ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
try {
    while((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        char [] characterArray = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i <  characterArray.length; i++){

            characters.add(characterArray[i]);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
char [] patternArray = phrase.toCharArray();
ArrayList<Character> pattern = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i <  patternArray.length; i++) {

    pattern.add(patternArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: List<> list = new LinkedList<> instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 9):

This code offers a nice illustration to why programming to interfaces is a good thing. You keep using this declaration pattern:

```
ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

If you wish to make `characters` a linked list, you would have to make changes in two places. If you used interface name for the declaration, like this

```
List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

the rest of your code would continue working, but you would be able to make a single change to convert to `LinkedList`:

```
List<Character> characters = new LinkedList<Character>();
```

Same goes for the declaration of your `pattern` variable.

> It is too slow and uses too much memory

Of course it does! Long linked lists take significantly more memory, so it's impractical to use them for character-by-character representations. Generally, conversions of strings to character lists is practical only when you deal with a small number of short strings. In other situations you would be better off with `String` objects, or `StringBuilder` objects if you need mutability.

Comment: I tried this bro, but it takes forever to run. It is too slow and uses too much memory

Comment: @bond007 - Well that probably means you should stick with `ArrayList` rather than chaning to `LinkedList`.